# Passing value of ID from partial view To the main View

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

** Controller Code **

I have the below code in my partial View and the id loan_no

```
<html>
<head>


</head>
<body>
    <table class="label-primary" style="width:110%" id="loan_type">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="floatleft" style="height:50px">
                    <div class="label" style="font-size:inherit">Loan Name:</div>

                    <strong>
                        @Html.DropDownList("loan_code",
                                                        (SelectList)ViewBag.loanTypes, "--Select Loan Product--",
                                                        htmlAttributes:new { required = "required",@class = "form-control chosen mandatory",
                                                            @id ="loan_code"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessage("loan_code", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </strong>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="label" style="font-size:inherit">*Loan No:</div>
                <span id="loan_no"></span>
            </td>

        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Main View Code This is the code in the View, the JavaScript function savePayslipInfo makes the Ajax request.I need the Value from id 'loan_no' from partial view to be passed to this main View.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function savePayslipInfo() {

        var current_loan_number = $("#loan_no").val();//id is from the partial View posted on the code above
        console.log(current_loan_number)
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:1079/loanapplication/save_Payslip_Info/?loan_no" + current_loan_number,
            data: {
                loan_no: $("#loan_no").val(),
                basic_salary: $("#basic_salary").val(),
                house_allowance: $("#house_allowance").val(),
                other_allowance: $("#other_allowance").val(),
                other_payment: $("#other_payment").val(),
                total_deduction: $("#total_deduction").val(),

            },
            success: function () {
                $('#msg').html("Payslip info saved successfully").fadeIn('slow');
                $('#msg').delay(4000).fadeOut('slow');
            }

        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: If you have input control with id `loan_no` you can use it in the JavaScript code of main view.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I dont have, I want to use it as a variable in the url.

Comment: you are doing `$("#loan_no").val(),` for that you need to have input control with id `loan_no`. You are having `loan_code` dropdown list in partial view, if that has the same value you want then you can use `$("#loan_code").val(),` too.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya so I can do a hidden input? Like <input type="hidden" id="loan_no"  />

Comment: Yes.. you can do hidden input too...

Answer (score 0):

Since I was trying to pass a value of the InnerText in html span tag to the url in Ajax
I used javascript 'document.getElementById("loan_no").innerText;'
Then Pass it like :

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:1079/loanapplication/save_Payslip_Info/?loan_no" + document.getElementById("loan_no").innerText,
            data: {
                loan_no: document.getElementById("loan_no").innerText,
                basic_salary: $("#basic_salary").val(),
                house_allowance: $("#house_allowance").val(),
                other_allowance: $("#other_allowance").val(),
                other_payment: $("#other_payment").val(),
                total_deduction: $("#total_deduction").val(),

            },
            success: function () {
                $('#msg').html("Payslip info saved successfully").fadeIn('slow');
                $('#msg').delay(4000).fadeOut('slow');
            }

        });
```